# Integrating AWS EC2, RDS and... S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I'm following this tutorial and 100% works like a charm :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/awsgsg-wah-linux.pdf

but, in that tutorial, it use Amazon EC2 and RDS only. I was wondering what if my servers scaled up into multiple EC2 instances then I need to update my PHP files.

do I have to distribute it manually across those instances? because, as far as I know, those instances are not synced each other.

so, I decided to use S3 as replacement of my /var/www so the PHP files is now centralised in one place.

so, whenever those EC2 scaled up, the files remains in one place and I don't need to upload to multiple EC2.

is this the best practice to have centralised file server (S3) for /var/www ? because currently I still having permission issue when it's mounted using s3fs.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your /var/www/ in S3 and when your instances scaled up have to make 'aws s3 sync' from your bucket, you can do that in the userdata. Also you have to select a 'master' instance where you make changes, a sync script upload changes to S3 and with rsync it copy changes to your alive FE. This is because if you have 3 FE that downloaded /var/www/ from S3 and you want to make a new change you would have to make a s3 sync in all your instances.
You can manage changes in your 'master' instance with inotify. Inotify can detect a change in /var/www/ and exec two commands, one could be aws s3 sync and then a rsync to the rest of your instances. You can get the list of your instances from the ELB through the AWS API.
The last thing is check the instance terminate protection in your 'master' instance.

Your architecture should look like here http://www.markomedia.com.au/scaling-wordpress-in-amazon-cloud/

Good look!!